# Conditional merging with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below which details additional calls into an area:

| CommsDate | Area | Day0 Incremental | Day1 Incremental | Day2 Incremental |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/24 | Sales | 43 | 36 | 29 |
| 01/01/24 | Service | 85 | 74 | 66 |
| 02/01/24 | Sales | 56 | 42 | 31 |
| 02/01/24 | Service | 73 | 62 | 49 |
| 03/01/24 | Sales | 48 | 32 | 24 |
| 03/01/24 | Service | 67 | 58 | 46 |

I am trying to calculate by date how many calls were received, so calls received for Sales on 1st Jan would be Day0_incremental for that date (43), 2nd Jan would be Day0 for 2nd Jan plus Day1 for 1st Jan (36+56) and 3rd Jan would be Day0 for 3rd Jan plus Day1 for 2nd Jan plus Day2 for 1st Jan (48+42+29), resulting in the below dataframe:

| CallDate | Sales | Service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/24 | 43 | 85 |
| 02/01/24 | 92 | 147 |
| 03/01/24 | 119 | 195 |
| 04/01/24 | 63 | 107 |
| 05/01/24 | 24 | 46 |

I have managed to create a shell of a dataframe for the second table with no values under the area columns, but at a loss as to the next steps:

```
df['CommsDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CommsDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
areaUnique = df['Area'].unique().tolist()
from datetime import timedelta
CallDate = pd.date_range(start=min(df['CommsDate']), end=max(df['CommsDate'])+timedelta(days=6), freq='D')

data = {area: [] for area in areaUnique}

dfNew = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfNew['CallDate'] = CallDate

dfNew = dfNew.melt(id_vars=['CallDate'], var_name='Area')

dfNew = dfNew.pivot(index='CallDate', columns='Area', values='value')

dfNew = dfNew.reset_index()

dfNew = dfNew[['CallDate'] + areaUnique]
```

I have started to write a for loop, but I've only got this far:

```
for i in range(1,len(areaUnique)+1):
    dfNew.columns(i) =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df['CommsDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CommsDate'], dayfirst=True)
tmp = df.pivot(index='CommsDate', columns='Area')

out = (tmp['Day0 Incremental']
       .add(tmp['Day1 Incremental'].shift(freq='1d'), fill_value=0)
       .add(tmp['Day2 Incremental'].shift(freq='2d'), fill_value=0)
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Or, programmatically with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) using the extracted number from the `DayX …` string:

```
from functools import reduce
import re

reg = re.compile(r'Day(\d+)')

df['CommsDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CommsDate'], dayfirst=True)
tmp = df.pivot(index='CommsDate', columns='Area')

out = reduce(lambda a,b: a.add(b, fill_value=0),
             (tmp[d].shift(freq=f'{reg.search(d).group(1)}d') for d in
              tmp.columns.get_level_values(0).unique())
            ).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Output:

```
   CommsDate  Sales  Service
0 2024-01-01   43.0     85.0
1 2024-01-02   92.0    147.0
2 2024-01-03  119.0    195.0
3 2024-01-04   63.0    107.0
4 2024-01-05   24.0     46.0
```

Comment: I just updated it to use a regex instead of the hardcoded position of the number in the `DayX …` string